# Maximum Recursion py2app

Tags: python, py2app

I am trying to make an executable for a Python program using py2app but receive a Recursion Error whenever I run.

```
python setup.py py2app
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
import pandas as pd

def combine_files(file1, file2, output_file):
    # Read the CSV files
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, na_values=['NA', 'N/A'])
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, na_values=['NA', 'N/A'])

    df1 = df1.rename(columns={'name': 'Player', 'fpts': 'Points'})
    df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Name': 'Player', 'Fpts': 'Points'})

    df1['Points'] *= 4
    df2['Points'] *= 3

    combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

    combined_df['Points'].fillna(combined_df.groupby('Player')['Points'].transform('first'), inplace=True)

    combined_df = combined_df.groupby('Player', as_index=False)['Points'].sum()

    combined_df['Points'] /= 7

    combined_df['Points'] = combined_df['Points'].round(2)

    combined_df.to_csv(output_file, index=False)

file1 = 'Data_1.csv'
file2 = 'Data_2.csv'
output_file = 'combined_output.csv'

combine_files(file1, file2, output_file)

print(f"The combined file '{output_file}' has been generated.")
```

And this is the setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['combine2.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'packages': ['pandas'],
    'argv_emulation': True,
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

This is the error I received:

```
/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
running py2app
creating /Users/miranda/Desktop/Combine/build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.11-standalone/app
creating /Users/miranda/Desktop/Combine/build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.11-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/miranda/Desktop/Combine/build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.11-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.11-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/python3.11-standalone/app/Frameworks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/miranda/Desktop/Combine/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 984, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1214, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1307, in run_normal
    mf = self.get_modulefinder()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1145, in get_modulefinder
    return find_modules(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 325, in find_modules
    find_needed_modules(mf, scripts, includes, packages)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 226, in find_needed_modules
    mf.run_script(path)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1142, in run_script
    self._scan_code(co, m)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1744, in _scan_code
    self._scan_ast(co, m)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1760, in _scan_ast
    imported_module = self._safe_import_hook(*args, **kwds)[0]
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1573, in _safe_import_hook
    mods = self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level, attr=attr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1158, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1247, in _find_head_package
    q = self._import_module(head, qname, parent)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1448, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1478, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1974, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1539, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(co, m)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1744, in _scan_code
    self._scan_ast(co, m)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1760, in _scan_ast
    imported_module = self._safe_import_hook(*args, **kwds)[0]
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1573, in _safe_import_hook
    mods = self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level, attr=attr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1159, in import_hook
    m = self._load_tail(q, tail)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1270, in _load_tail
    result = self._import_module(head, mname, result)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1448, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1478, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1974, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1539, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(co, m)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1744, in _scan_code
    self._scan_ast(co, m)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1760, in _scan_ast
    imported_module = self._safe_import_hook(*args, **kwds)[0]
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1573, in _safe_import_hook
    mods = self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level, attr=attr)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1159, in import_hook
    m = self._load_tail(q, tail)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1270, in _load_tail
    result = self._import_module(head, mname, result)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1448, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1478, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 428, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 428, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 428, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 428, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 428, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "/Users/miranda/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/ast.py", line 418, in visit
    return visitor(node)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I deleted a good bit of the recursion error info from the middle due to exceeding the maximum characters.